# How to Get Average Values with Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I can easily get a single average value using 'where'.

```
       $rate = DB::table('reviews')
            ->where('p_id', 2)
            ->avg('rate');
```

But I don't know how to get all average value GROUP by p_id.

```
id p_id rate 
1   2    3
2   2    4
3   2    3
4   1    4
5   2    3
6   2    2
7   2    5
8   3    3
9   3    2
```

So Results I want are like below:

p_id 1: Average VALUE

p_id 2: Average VALUE

p_id 3: Average VALUE

Answer (score 0):

You can use selectRaw and then use groupBy.

code:

```
$result = DB::table('reviews')
              ->groupBy('p_id')
              ->selectRaw('p_id, avg(rate)')
              ->get();`
```

You should check your database documentation whether can use avg function in your database. I using mariadb and it support avg function in database.